# How to set up HVR-2250 TV card in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: hvr-2250

I have the HVR-2250, the system does see it, card 3,but I can't figure out how to get it going to watch TV. I have My TV and Kaffine.
Any body have a step by step by step?
It works great in Windows 7 64 bit with WMC.
I would like to switch over to Linux and have some of the same abilities.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I just picked up 2 of these cards for my linux box and ran into the same issue. however all is not lost. ~Pending on what version of Ubuntu you are running ( I am running 12.10 studio version) the command is quite easy and should work with any *buntu distro 8.10 and up.

Download the firmware file from this link:
http://www.steventoth.net/linux/hvr22xx/firmwares/4019072/NXP7164-2010-03-10.1.fw

after you download that folder change to the directory that your download is in (/home/

Copy the firmware file to the firmware directory

```
sudo cp NXP7164-2010-03-10.1.fw /lib/firmware
```

then, reload the saa7164 module:

```
sudo rmmod saa7164
sudo modprobe saa7164
```

Comment: Can you be clearer with your question. What kind of cards are you having problems with? Seems like a graphics card. Could you provide names of the graphics card to help dig more information?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to DigitalRazor's answer I was able to setup my wintv-hvr-2250 under Ubuntu 12.04.1 (64bit). The link in his answer has a typo. Here is the [correct link](http://www.steventoth.net/linux/hvr22xx/firmwares/4019072/NXP7164-2010-03-10.1.fw).

The `sha1sum` for the file is `6d23a53acb339a0cc229312306c05d03c0770f9a`

I've also uploaded a copy [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xi58bbnow0mfd4q/NXP7164-2010-03-10.1.fw).

I intended to use VLC at first but it requires more manual setup. Kaffeine is much easier to use.